# Parse Form Data in Perl to remove all non alphanumeric / punctuation

Tags: mysql, perl

In web form entries we are seeing  strange characters being used such as:

â€™ (windows 1252 encoded)

or

ðŸ’• (emoji)

or

Ã¢Â€Â¬ (no idea but think it's windows 1252)

For some of them I can use a regex to simply replace them with the utf-8 equivalent but I would prefer to use some sort of regex or encoding that efficiently removes them.

I've set the DB Table in MYSQL to utf-8

What is the best and most ideal solution for this in perl?  Or can I do it in the mysql table instead?

Comment: Looks like somewhere on the way the encoding breaks. The client sends over utf8, you want to safe utf8, but along the way it gets treated as something else, like CP1252. Do you want to fix that, or do you want to discard this data? (hint: throwing away your users' data is seldom a good idea)

Comment: ideally I would like to keep the data but encode it correctly so it can be displayed in the future

Answer (score 2):

`â€™` is U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`’`) encoded using UTF-8, then displayed on a cp1252 terminal.

`ðŸ’•` is U+1F495 TWO HEARTS () similarly mistreated.

`Ã¢Â€Â¬`is U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING encoded using UTF-8, then encoded using UTF-8 a second time, then displayed on a cp1252 terminal.

---

> *What is the best and most ideal solution for this in perl? Or can I do it in the mysql table instead?*

Depends.

If there's a bug in your Perl program, you should fix it!

If the data is bad in the database, you should fix that (and whatever is putting bad data in the database)!

As it stands, you provided no evidence one way or another. (Providing the field's encoding and `SELECT HEX(field)` would reveal if the data is in the database or not.)

Comment: agreed I want to keep the data and encode it correctly preferably in the perl before it gets added to the database.

Comment: Then provide the requested information. When you've fixed your question by adding the necessary information to it, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This should remove all special characters. You can check ORD table to make sure nothing that you need gets removed.

```
$line =~ s/(.)/(ord($1) > 127) ? "" : $1/egs;
```

Comment: useful if i wanted to remove them as a dirty last resort

Comment: "but I would prefer to use some sort of regex or encoding that efficiently removes them" - if you do not want them to be removed you might want to rephrase your request